# Block missing from admin

Tags: blocks

I was wondering if anyone has been able to successfully resolve the issue of the missing custom blocks from the admin list in drupal yet?

I have been struggling with this problem for 2 days now.

I have scanned the internet and forums (including this one) and tried every trick suggested,  and found many examples of what should work, but each time it does not.

I have tried unregistering/registering, clearing out the caches automatically and manually in the DB, all to no avail, I simply don't see the elusive block in my admin.

I went to the database and checked out the blocks table, and I don't see it registered there, I don't know if that gives a clue?

Between I have tried all of the tips in this posting and the links.

I have included by latest web cut and paste, if there is anything you think I might be doing wrong, I would really appreciate your help.

This is the code I am currently using :

```
function customblock_block_info() { 
  $blocks = array(); 
  $blocks['customblock_abc'] = array(
    'info' => t('Customblock'),
    'region' => BLOCK_REGION_NONE,
    'status' => 1,
  );

  return $blocks;
}

function customblock_block_view($delta = '') { 
  switch ($delta) { 
    case 'customblock_abc': 
      $block['subject'] = 'Block title'; 
      $block['content'] = 'Hello world!'; 
      break;
  }
  return $block; // dont forget to the return the $block!
}
}
```

Comment: Code seems to be ok. Did you enable your 'customblock' module?

Comment: At the end of your code you have too much curly braces. The last curly brace results in a syntax error.